# Joomla component media manager to select pdf

Tags: joomla-3.x

I wrote a component and need a field there where the user can pick a pdf from the media manager.
When I set the field-type in the field list to «media», the media-manager only shows images.

How do I make it show all files instead of images only?

Answer (score 3):

I have not tested this in later Joomla versions, but at least in 2.5.x it was possible to display a list of files in a folder in the form of the drop-down.

The path is hardcoded and rather limited , BUT for some use cases it may just do the trick and provide the flexibility needed.

Ladies and gentleman, presenting the `filelist`:

```
    <field 
        name="yourfile" 
        type="filelist"
        label="COM_EXAMPLE_FIELD_YOURFILE_LABEL" 
        description="COM_EXAMPLE_FIELD_YOURFILE_DESC" 
        directory="media/com_example/files/"
        hide_none="true"
        hide_default="true"
    />
```

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is still interested, I've described a solution [here](http://www.richardbutterworth.co.uk/blog/19-the-joomla-media-form-field), where a plug-in is used to override the imageslist view of com_media so that it shows all files in the media manager. I've put the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/rb-dmd/rbdmdmediaoverride).

I'd be first to admit that this is a less than elegant solution, but it works for the project I developed it for. I would treat this code as a starting point for your project, not a polished solution.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. It's generally better to include the solution (or part of it) in the answer. If the link breaks the answer is useless.

Comment: I used your plugin in Joomla 3 as well. Because this issue is still not resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Extending on the suggestion by @ValentinDespa, you can use the `filelist` form field type, and add a `filter` parameter. Any [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) can be added here, see example below for how to filter PDF-files only.

```
<field type="filelist" name="pdf" label="Select PDF" directory="images" filter="\.pdf$"/>
```

[image]

This works fine in Joomla 3.x, BTW.

Comment: Upvote for the regex.

Answer (score 1):

The Media form field type is used to select an image. So it filters out other files.
Have a look at [Joomla documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_types) for the available standard form fields types. You might also want to consider to create your own custom modal form field type for your component.

Comment: That's a joke, right? The media manager lets me upload PDFs, video and whatnot, but it won't let me actually SELECT them? I'm forced to write my own form-field?
Isn't there a way to tell the Media-field to NOT exclude other files?
(I know you're not responsible for this behavior, so don't take this rant-like reply personally :)

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I remember, the filter is actually hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JCE editor with plugin file manager.

https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/downloads/plugins/file-manager