# How to allow media manager open video files

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, media-manager, system-plugin

How can select a video file (mp4, ogv, webm ...) in a plugin as parameter?

I intend to select a video file in a plugin parameters, tried field type `media` but videos files are not listed. Using field type `filelist` they are listed.

The only way is to use `filelist` field type?

Comment: media field type lists only images

Answer (score 6):

The best way to allow video selection in an extension field is to use a custom field. For an introduction to custom fields, take a look at [this article from Joomla! Documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type).

In its simplest form, you can simply extend the `filelist` field type and make it list video files using the formats you want. Here's an example (based on the `imagelist` field type):

File: **/modules/mod_YOURMODULE/models/fields/videos.php**

```
<?php

defined('JPATH_PLATFORM') or die;

JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('filelist');

class JFormFieldVideos extends JFormFieldFileList
{
    protected $type = 'ImageList';
    protected function getOptions()
    {
        // Define the vide file type filter. Edit as needed.
        $this->filter = '\.mov$|\.mpg$|\.mp4$|\.ogv$|\.webm$|\.mts$|\.avi$|\.wmv$';
        return parent::getOptions();
    }
}
```

File: **/modules/mod_YOURMODULE/mod_YOURMODULE.xml**

```
<fieldset name="videos" addfieldpath="/modules/mod_YOURMODULE/models/fields">
       <field name="videos" type="Videos" label="Select a video" description="" directory="images"  /> 
</fieldset>
```

It's not as elegant as the media manager popup, but the same method can be used to create a more complex form if you know how.

The same can also be achieved by adding filters to the `filelist` form field directly:

```
<field type="filelist" name="test" label="Video filter" directory="images" filter="\.mov$|\.mpg$|\.mp4$|\.ogv$|\.webm$|\.mts$|\.avi$|\.wmv$" />
```

(A related question with a couple of answers can be [found here](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/928/joomla-component-media-manager-to-select-pdf).)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add proper extensions and mime types in com_media settings. If that will not help it is possible you will have to create your own field type for that.

Comment: Adding extensions didn't work but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use JCE editor with plugin media manager addon.

https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/downloads/plugins/media-manager